# Finding standard error

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

I have been doing the following problem and there is something I do not understand:

SCB's political party preference survey is conducted twice a year. Random selected people will answer the question "Which party would you vote for if it was a parliamentary election?". Below you will find the results of SCB's measurements in May 2018 and November 2017 for the "Alliansen", the "Rödgröna", and other parties("Övriga").
[image]

Estimate the change in support for the "Rödgröna" party and the standard error for this estimate.

So, in the solutions I have for the change of support, that $X~Bin(4632, p1)$ and $Y~Bin(4715, p2)$. Then $(p1)^*obs = 1945/4632 ≈ 0.4199$ $(p2)^*obs = 2126/4715 ≈ 0.4509$.

So, the change in support is:
[image]

Now, the part that I do not understand, it says: The standard error is an estimate of the standard deviation of the estimation. We estimate $p1-p2$ with $X/4632 - Y/4715$ that has the variance
[image]

Finally, the error:
[image]

My question: Why is $V(X)$ above divided by $4632^2$ and not just $4632$? I don't fully understand why is the standard error calculated this way? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to calculate $$Var\left(\frac{X}{n_1}+\frac{Y}{n_2}\right)$$

It is supposed that $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Thus  we have $Var\left(\frac{X}{n_1}\right)+Var\left(\frac{Y}{n_2}\right)$

Now you can apply the rule $Var(cX)=c^2\cdot Var(X)$, where $c$ is an arbitrary constant. $\frac{1}{n_1}$ and $\frac{1}{n_2}$ are constants as well. Therefore we get

$$\frac{1}{n_1^2}\cdot Var(X)+\frac{1}{n_2^2}\cdot Var(Y)$$

Comment: Why is it $$Var\left(\frac{X}{n_1}+\frac{Y}{n_2}\right)$$, and not just $$Var\left({X}+{Y}\right)$$ ?

Comment: Actually you want the variance of the sum of $X / n_1$ and $Y / n_2$. But  luckily it is supposed that they are independent and thus $Cov(X,Y)=0$

Comment: I think you´ve edit your comment. What you want  to calculate is  the variance of the sum of the two **proportions**. $X$ and $Y$ are binomial distributed .

Comment: That is what I am wondering about, why do I need the sum of two proportions, and not just $Var(X + Y)$?

Comment: Usually the results of  election polls and election results are presented in proportions (percentages) and not in  absolute numbers of voters. But you´re right that it is not explicitly mentioned in the exercise.